# Google Chart: How to draw the vertical axis for LineChart when x-axis is a date?

Tags: php, google-api, linechart

I want to draw a chart in which x-axis is a date.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'history');
data.addRows([
[{v: 1, f:'11-05-2010'},   10],
[{v: 2, f:'11-05-2011'},   20],
[{v: 3, f:'11-05-2012'},   34],
[{v: 4, f:'11-05-2013'},   48]
]);
var options = {
    title: '<?php echo $strings["updates_task"]; ?>',
    legend: 'none',
        lineWidth: 2,
    hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9 },

    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        gridlines: {
            color: 'none',
            count: 5
        }
    },
    colors: ['#FF0000'],
    pointSize: 10,
    pointShape: 'square',
    width:1200,
    height:500 
    }; 
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart')); 
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

When I used x as string then date is showing but not the vertical line.
When I used x as number then vertical lines are shown but 2.5,5,7.5 are shown in place on date. But I want to show both. How can I show both?
[image]